# 2D Tile Map Generation from Tileset

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, 2d, tile

I have been looking all over and seen lot of questions of this nature.
My problem is much simpler than generating a 3D world with heights and such.

I'd like to generate a 2D map in a limited space (15x15, 20x20 ...) based on a tileset.
Here is a random example what a simple result could look like:

[image]

Is anyone aware of an algorithm which is capable of executing such a task?

Answer (score 0):

- First, you should create a spritesheet that will have all the tiles you need.
- Then you should create a class 'Tile', that will be able to render yourself (tile will be of fixed size, so it will not be hard)
- Then, you should create a level. I mean, you should create a description of your level. You can do it in text format, xml or you can generate it randomly. For example, your level:
  GGGGGGGG
  GGGGGGGG
  GGGBBGGG
  GGGGGGGG
  Where one letter means one tile (G is for grass, B is for bridge).
- Then, when you've done it, you should iterate through your level descritpion and render it.

UPD. Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I use an excellent piece of software: "Tiled". It's open source and great! You cat create levels by drag and drop. And when completed you can export your level to xml, txt, json and other formats.

Comment: "Then, you should create a level" - That's what this question is about (at least as I read it).

Comment: Yes, the problem is the creation of a level which makes some sense